# SumIF + Index + Match formula

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have the following table and I'm trying to get a formula so that I can get the sum of a center's result between two dates i.e. Sum all numbers for Bunbury between dates 08-05-17 and 06-05-17 (Result: 950). I've used the following formula but it gives me #VALUE!

My formula:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(B:G,MATCH("Bunbury",$A15:$BC15,0),0),$A$16:$A$21,"<=" & $J3,$A$16:$A$21,">=" & $I3)
```

[image: Can someone please help?]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zGMd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your match should match the column, not the row in B:G.

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($B$16:$G$21, 0, MATCH("Bunbury", $B$15:$G$15, 0)), $A$16:$A$21,"<="&$J3, $A$16:$A$21,">="&$I3)
'alternate
=SUMIFS(INDEX($B:$G, 0, MATCH("Bunbury", $B$15:$G$15, 0)), $A:$A,"<="&$J3, $A:$A,">="&$I3)
```

There's also no need to look further than column G for a match and you should start looking in column B; e.g. $B15:$G15. J3 should be the end date and I3 the start date (not evident from your sample image).

I missed one problem the first time around. INDEX cannot reference all of the rows in B:G; it can only reference the same number of rows as $A$16:$A$21 (the date comparison range). Alternately, if there is no rogue data that would skew results, the date comparison ranges could be made full column. They have to be comparable ranges.